# SSRS Lookupset showing every item associated with the account in one cell

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am currently working on making an itemized list with the associated contract prices but because of how the tables are setup I cannot have it all in the same dataset, so I've been using the lookupset expression, but I can't find a way to separate the items in the column into individual rows. All of my prices are correct, but every item associated with that contract account shows in each price cell.

[image: This is the lookupset that I've been using and I've tried multiple different joins for it but it all leads to the same issue]

| Item | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Item1 Item2 | price |
| Item3 Item4 |  |
| Item5 Item6 |  |
| Item1 Item2 | price |
| Item3 Item4 |  |
| Item5 Item6 |  |

I just need a solution to break up the items into their own cells with the price lining up and if I need to add code to it then that's possible but I can't find the way to go.

Comment: Edit your question and show what the data looks like in each of the datasets, also show what the expected result based on your sample data shoudl look like.. It's difficult (for me at least) to understand exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will not be able to break up JOINed data into separate rows.

I think your easiest solution is a subreport.

Make a new report with the other dataset. Create a table with the Items (and price?). You could copy your current report and delete the items you don't need.

Then add the subreport to the table in your original report with the CustomerCode as the Parameter.

[image]

Easier to make and runs faster than the LookUpset.

Comment: This does seem to be the best course of action but now an issue that is popping up is that I am getting a sub report cannot be shown error and I've tried looking into if the security settings are the same, but I cannot figure out a solution to this problem, do you have any idea?

Comment: @SUCRAM - If you can run it in Visual Studio, it usually gives a somewhat helpful error message. I don;t think it would be security if you have access to both.

Comment: Unfortunately loading it in the program causes it to endlessly spin loading so I can't see any errors, but I've been deploying it to see the results and that is where I am seeing the error. Thanks for your help by the way!